# Showing the sum of magnitudes of complex coefficients implies the polynomial has all roots in the unit disc.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, polynomials

This is question 1) of section 56 of Munkres book on topology.  It states that for a complex polynomial $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+... +a_0$ such that $\Sigma_{i=0}^n|a_i|<1$, then $f(x)$ has all it's roots in the unit disc.
As suggested in the text, I managed to prove that the polynomial $g(x)=1+a_{n-1}x+... +a_0x^n$ isn't zero on the unit disc.  From here I also managed to demonstrate that all of $g(x)$'s zeros lie outside the disc.  Now I'm stuck trying conclude that $f$'s roots are in the disc but I'm not too sure...

Comment: now consider $x^n(g(\frac{1}{x}))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark that $x^nf(1/x)=g(x)$, so $g(1/x)=0$ is equivalent to $f(x)=0$ $g(1/x)=0$ implies that $1/x$ is outside of the unit disc and $x$ is inside the unit disc.